# How do i use the scanner method to recreate a picture

Tags: java

I have to use scanner (in my PicturReader.java class) to recreate a picture from my PictureWriter.java class. Can anyone help me out i know this is a simple problem but im lost

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use the Scanner class because it's meant to read in primitive types. I don't know how you are saving the image, but it's in a file then you need to read the bytes back.

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("filename.jpg","r");
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()]; //Omitted a check if the file is longer than an int
file.readFully(bytes);
```